# .NET ComponentModel.DataAnnotations issue with RegularExpression attribute

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have to validate a string that's supposed to contain an hour number (e.g. 00 to 23).

I hence set an annotation like:

```
 [RegularExpression("[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]", ErrorMessage = "Error")]
 public string JobStartHour {...}
```

Unfortunately, this regex doesn't match the inputs from 20 to 23, as it's supposed to do (IMHO).

Doesn't this `RegularExpression` attribute use the plain old Regex.IsMatch ?

```
Regex.IsMatch("22", "[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]")
```

returns true...

**Edit:** I know, using a string isn't the best idea so as to store a number, nevertheless, this regex issue is annoying.

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it works with "0" or "00". Hope this sorts out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why this regex isn't correctly interpreted, but a solution is to implement a [CustomValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which is pretty handy.

```
   [CustomValidation(typeof(MyCustomValidation), "Validate24Hour")]
     public string JobStartHour {...}

...

  public class MyCustomValidation
    {
        public static ValidationResult Validate24Hour(string candidate)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
         ...
            if (isValid)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Error");
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will work. I ran into the [same thing](http://pretzelsteelersfan.blogspot.com/2011/11/i-was-working-on-some-code-that-stores.html). It has to do with using parens to correctly establish the groupings. If the RegExAttribute can't figure it out, it seems to just quit at the pipe symbol.

Here's a unit test.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckHours()
    {
      var pattern = "([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])|([0-9])";
      int cnt = 0;

      var hours = new string[]
        { "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
          "01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09",
          "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19",
          "20","21","22","23" };

      var attribute = new RegularExpressionAttribute(pattern);
      bool isMatchOk = false;
      bool isAttrOk = false;

      foreach (var hour in hours)
      {
        isMatchOk = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(hour, pattern);
        isAttrOk = attribute.IsValid(hour);

        if (isMatchOk & isAttrOk)
        { cnt += 1; }
        else
        { Debug.WriteLine(hour + " / " 
          + isMatchOk.ToString() + " / "
          + isAttrOk.ToString()); }
      }

      Assert.AreEqual(32, cnt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[RegularExpression("2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Error")]
 public string JobStartHour {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group the `|` to work properly.

I successfully tried, which should be exactly your regex but grouped and limited to start & end:

```
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])$
```

Your named `Regex.IsMatch` line returns true on every expression on my machine.